# Как можно считать все элементы массива по условию?

Tags: python, алгоритм, list

Как можно реализовать программу, чтобы считать количество элементов массива, пока каждый следующий элемент больше предыдущего, а потом вывести их максимальную длину?

Comment: пройдитесь по телу массива и если следующий меньше  предыдущего то найти индекс следующего и это и будет его длина

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала мы определим `max_amount = 0` как максимальное число возрастающих элементов и `amount = 1` как текущее число элементов. Затем мы запустим цикл со второго элемента цикла (первый уже зачтён, отсюда и `amount = 1`), внесём `last_elem` как первый элемент массива и проведём следующие шаги:

- Считаем следующий элемент массива как `elem` и сравним его с предыдущим;
- Если `elem > last_elem`, то увеличиваем `amount` на 1;
- Если предыдущий шаг не прошёл, то, если `max_amount < amount`, заменяем максимальную цепь на `amount`. В любом случае цепь начинается заново, и тогда `amount = 1`;
- Если в списке есть элементы, переходим к следующему, иначе выходим из цикла.

Если мы вышли из цикла, то мы должны дополнительно сравнить оставшееся значение `amount` с `max_amount` и последовать шагу 3 (например, если список оканчивается возрастающей последовательностью: `[1, 9, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14]`).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте пройдись по телу массива, и если следующий элемент массива будет меньше предыдущего то найдите индекс следующего , и это и будет его длина

```
mas = [2, 3, 4, 1]
for i in range(len(mas) - 1):
    if mas[i + 1] < mas[i]:
        print(mas.index(mas[i + 1]))
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# подключаем модуль псевдослучайных чисел
import random
# генерируем список
lst_random = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(100)]
# выводим случайный список
print(lst_random)

curent_len_data = []
max_len_data = []

# Бежим по циклу
for i in range(1, len(lst_random)):
    # если текущий элемент больше предыдущего, то запоминаем
    if lst_random[i] > lst_random[i-1]:
        curent_len_data.append(lst_random[i-1])
    else:
        # Текущий больше или равен предыдущему
        # проверяем размер текущего списка с максимальным. Запоминаем его, если он больше
        if len(max_len_data) < len(curent_len_data):
            max_len_data = curent_len_data
        # Обнуляем параметры для подсчетов следующего списка
        len_curent = 0
        curent_len_data = []

# Выводим итоги
print(f'Максимальная длина: {len(max_len_data)}')
print(f'Максимальная продолжительность списка: {max_len_data}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из комментариев выше пришёл к такому решению своей проблемы:

```
max_len = -99**99
count = 0 
for j in range(len(massive)-1):
    if massive[j] < massive[j+1]:
        count += 1 
        if max_len < count:
            max_len = count 
    else:
         count = 1 
print(max_len)
```

Comment: Если ответы приведенные выше помогли вам то отметьте их принятыми и полезными

Comment: @assert отметил.